# Getting rid of dollar signs in PHP in a best way

Tags: php, coding-style

I hate PHP dollar signs. With that in mind I tried and found a way to access variables and function parameters without using them.

First, to get value of a variable I used `get_defined_vars`:

```
// echo $foo;
echo get_defined_vars()['foo'];
```

That was easy. To assign value to the variable I used `extract`:

```
// $foo = 'Hello World!';
extract(['foo' => 'Hello World!']);
```

To access function parameters: `func_get_args`:

```
// function print_string($msg) {
function print_string() {
    extract(['msg' => func_get_args()[0]]);
    echo get_defined_vars()['msg']; 
}
```

But after all its ugly, messy, impractical. I'd like to simplify it, add some syntactic sugar. I don't know how. I was looking going in crazy directions like making [array constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641336/why-cant-php-have-a-constant-object), classes with modifiable members etc. but I couldn't get to anything prettier.

What can I do more to simplify above code? (If such a question is not to be asked on this stack exchange board then I kindly ask moderators to move it to the proper one.)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to switch to a language that doesn't use them?

Comment: But I love PHP. I just hate the dollars.

Comment: Just stick with dollars. Thats the best you will ever get in PHP.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but the only recommendation here I can give to such a statement is "grow up and become a professional". Love and hate is not something you should feel towards minor syntactical issues of a programming language, there are more important things in life.

Answer (score 5):

> I hate PHP dollar signs. With that in mind I tried and found a way to access variables and function parameters without using them.

If you're going to code in PHP, then *just get used to them*.  Seriously.

As I think you're realising, trying to make one language "work like" another is just going to cripple your coding, trying to bend the [new] language in ways that are unnatural to it and, therefore, [far] more likely to go wrong.

We see this kind of argument a lot between 'C' and Java Developers, where they know one of these languages, start trying to use the other and want to make the new (and slightly scary) world of their new language all cosy and comfortable and syntactically akin to their old one.

It *just doesn't work*.

> What can I do more to simplify above code?

Write your PHP code *as* PHP.

To mis-quote Dr. Baronovich from the 1982 movie, Firefox:

> You must think in *PHP*.
>
> You can't think in *some other language* and transpose it.
>
> You must think in *PHP*.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with the other answers, if you have a strong opinion against this syntax, I think you'd be better off with another language.

HOWEVER, I'd like to differ from the other answers a bit.

Languages evolve all the time and sometimes requirements/implementations evolve faster than languages. Javascript is such a case - standards evolve but browsers lag behind.
In case of javascript, a very common solution is to use babel (or similar) which translates advanced functionality (that doesn't run ) into code that does.

This sort of flow is not common in PHP at all, as far as I know. But that does not mean it isn't possible.

Some people did it already, here are a few examples:

1. [infection/include-interceptor](https://github.com/infection/include-interceptor) is composer library that allows you to swap one include file with another. The core functionality of how this is achieved is by [overriding the file stream wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.file.php). I guess it might impact speed quite a bit though.
2. Generics in PHP [ircmaxell/PhpGenerics](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PhpGenerics) or [mrsuh/php-generics](https://github.com/mrsuh/php-generics) - a more relevant example to what you're asking. Basically they convert source code with generics into target code without (by hooking into composer).

So you could have something that identifies variables without the sigil and generates code with it.

The next point of annoyance would be the IDE...they will naturally complain about all sorts of syntax errors - but there are ways around it as well.

You just have to ask yourself if it is really worth that trouble.